# Variance of quotient of Poisson random variable and sum of the Poisson sample

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, poisson-distribution

Let

$$Y_1\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1)\\Y_2\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2),$$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2>0$.

What is the variance of $$\frac{Y_1} {Y_1+Y_2}?$$

Or more general, what is the variance of $$\frac{X_1} {X_1+ \cdots +X_n},$$where $X_i\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$, $i=1,...,n$?

**EDIT:**

This idea came to mind: It is well-known that if $Y_1\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1)$ and $Y_2\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2)$, where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, then $Y_1|Y_1+Y_2\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(y_1+y_2,p)$. Since the variance of a Binomially distributed random variable is $np(1-p)$, I just need to find the MLE of $p$.

Could this be a solution to my problem?

Comment: you could approximate it with a Taylor series, as described here: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf. The first order approximation to the variance of the ratio is $$\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\sum_j \lambda_j}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\sum_j \lambda_j}\right)$$

Comment: May I pose the consideration that the variance you seek is not defined? The sum of Poissons in the denominator will be Poisson ... and notably include 0 with discrete mass --> such that 1/denominator will yield infinite expressions.

Comment: @wolfies because of the dependence between them $\sum_j X_j = 0 \implies X_1 = 0$ so we'll never have a non-zero number divided by 0

Comment: So you'll have 0/0. It's still undefined.

Comment: So my "binomial-idea" is not valid?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? Is it the variance of $\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}$ or the variance of $Y1|Y1+Y2$? Also, is the zero scenario a problem for you or not - is this theory or practice?

Comment: It is the variance of $Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$ I want. It comes from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: I agree with wolfies. It is not defined.

Comment: I though think that this is not a problem for me, since what I really want to do is to construct a Wald test statistic, where $W=Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$ is the estimator. And the Wald test is a large-sample test.

Comment: As pointed out in comments, with a certain positive (maybe small, but always positive) probability, the expression $Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$ becomes $0/0$, so the random variable $Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$ is not unambiguously defined. You must clarify your question, how do you define your random variable in that case?